# Calling classes in a switch statement?

Tags: java, class, methods, switch-statement

There are three programs to run different function and I am told to call them depending on a numbered option the user input. First I put my programs on before adding in a switch statement at the end. I get errors varying in the switch statement - what exactly do I need to put in those braquets for each case? The parameters?

I get errors including error' class expected.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math;

public class HelperMethod{
    public static boolean BookNumber(String a) {
        char f;
        int e, g, h;
        int result = 0;

        System.out.println ("Please enter a thirteen digit number");
        String a = scanner.nextLine();

        if (a.length() == 13){
            for (int i = 0; i < 13; i ++) {
                f = a.charAt(i);
                e = Character.digit(f, 10); 
                if (i % 2 == 0) {
                    g = e * 1;
                    result = result + g;
                } else {
                    g = e * 3;
                    result = result + g;
                }
            }
            System.out.println ("The added sum of you numbers is " + result);
            if (result % 10 == 0) {
                System.out.println ("This combination IS a ISBN number");
            } else {
                System.out.println ("This is NOT an ISBN number");
            } 
        } else {
            System.out.println ("This combination is not thirteen digits long");
        }
    }

    public static boolean NewtonsMethod (double guess) {
        double guess, fX, fPrimeX, newGuess;

        System.out.println ("enter in a value give"); 
        guess = userInputScanner.nextDouble();
        System.out.println ("Your guess is " + guess);
         double guess; 

        while (true) {
            fX = (6 * Math.pow (guess,4)) - (13 * Math.pow (guess,3)) - (18 * Math.pow (guess,2)) + (7 * guess) + 6;
            fPrimeX = (24 * Math.pow (guess,3)) - (39 * Math.pow (guess,2)) - 36 * guess + 7;
            newGuess = guess - (fX / fPrimeX);
            System.out.println ("A possible root is " + newGuess);
            if (Math.abs(newGuess - guess) < 0.00001) {
                break;
            } else {
                guess = newGuess;
            }
        }
        System.out.println ("The root is: " + newGuess);
    }

    public static void QuadraticFormula (double a, double b, double c) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Input 
        System.out.println("Please enter an a value:");
        double a = keyboard.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Please enter a b value:");
        double b = keyboard.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Please enter a c value:");
        double c = keyboard.nextDouble();

        // Calculations
        double discriminant = b * b - 4 * a * c;
        double rootOne = 0, rootTwo = 0;

        // Option A
        if (discriminant < 0) {
            System.out.println("There are no roots!");
        } else if (discriminant > 0){
            rootOne = (-b + Math.sqrt(discriminant)) / (2 * a);
            rootTwo = (-b - Math.sqrt(discriminant)) / (2 * a);
            System.out.println("Your roots are: " + rootOne + " and " + rootTwo);
        } else {
            rootOne = (-b + Math.sqrt(discriminant)) / (2 * a);
            System.out.println("Your unique root is: " + rootOne);
        }

        // Option B
        if (discriminant < 0) {
            System.out.println("There are no roots!");
        } else {
            rootOne = (-b + Math.sqrt(discriminant)) / (2 * a);
            rootTwo = (-b - Math.sqrt(discriminant)) / (2 * a);
            if (discriminant > 0) {
                System.out.println("Your roots are: " + rootOne + " and " + rootTwo);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Your unique root is: " + rootOne);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Scanner userInputScanner = new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.println ("You have three options. press one for the quadratic Formula, 2 for the newtons Method, and 3 for an ISBN checker.");
        int input = userInputScanner.nextInt();

        switch (input) {
            case 1:
                NewtonsMethod (double guess);
                break;
            case 2:
                BookNumber(String a);
                break;
            case 3: 
                QuadraticFormula (double a, double b, double c);
                break; 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Beware - After copying this code to my IDE, it marked 28 errors.

Comment: Your code is very confused. You are passing values to methods, but also having those methods read the values from input, and you are including the type name in the parameter when calling a method.

Comment: looks like you need to read Java a little bit more .. before asking questions here.
While something like :  NewtonsMethod(double guess); is called method signature,  NewtonsMethod(guess); is called method call. what you need in your switch statement is a method call NOT a method signature. you have to call an already defined/implemented method though :)

Comment: I suggest you to read some beginners guide to Java such as Bruce Eckel "[Thinking in Java](http://mindview.net/Books/TIJ4)".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you have a number of syntax errors here:

```
NewtonsMethod(double guess);
```

You are attempting to call a method, but this looks like a declaration.  You have correct method invocations elsewhere, like, for instance:  `Math.sqrt(discriminant)`.  So that should look like:

```
NewtonsMethods(guess);
```

However, those methods don't look like they should be taking arguments at all.

```
public static boolean NewtonsMethod (double guess) {
    double guess, fX, fPrimeX, newGuess; 
    System.out.println ("enter in a value give"); 
    guess = userInputScanner.nextDouble();
    ...
```

You haven't got anything to pass into them when you invoke them, and you collect user input for those variables within the method body.  This leads to your declared method local variables colliding with those arguments, causing more syntax errors.  So, just don't pass any arguments into them, and your declarations look something like:

```
public static boolean NewtonsMethod (double guess) {
```

Your return types are problematic also.  You declare your methods with boolean return type, but never return a value. Doesn't seem to be much need for returning a boolean here, so I'd just give them a void return type:

```
public static void NewtonsMethod (double guess) {
```

After that, I only see three other syntax errors.  You have two places where you are trying to use a `Scanner` you haven't initialized yet.  You initialize them in `QuadraticFormula` and `main` though, so follow that pattern.  Also, you have declared the variable `guess` twice in Newton's method.  Fix that.  That should at least get you compiled, I believe.  I leave logic errors to you mostly, except this one that just jumps right out at me:  The numbers you tell the user to press don't do what you say they do.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I made most of the changes you suggested. However, I still don't understand what to put in the parameters of each method statement for each three programs. For example, my teacher says the Quadratic formula has 3 doubles (which would be a, b, and c right?). So when I call the three methods in that switch statement at the end of the code, do I put: QuadraticFormula (a, b, c); ?

Comment: Never mind! I got it - Thanks everyone for the constructive criticism.